# get height of ColumnHeaders in .net WinForms ListView (in details mode)

Tags: c#, .net, listview, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get  the header height of a Listview - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538906/how-do-i-get-the-header-height-of-a-listview-c)

> **Possible duplicate:**  [How do I get the header height of a Listview - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538906/how-do-i-get-the-header-height-of-a-listview-c)

Hello,
do you know if it is possible to find out the height of header of a ListView in Windows Forms application when it's switched to Details mode?

I'd like to find this out because I want to know the height of the area where the ListViewItems are located and I think it's ListView.ClientArea.Height - *height of columns*.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I get the header height of a Listview - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538906/how-do-i-get-the-header-height-of-a-listview-c) for a solution.